# How to tell NVIDIA driver to ignore X completely

Tags: nvidia, xorg, cuda

I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 on a GPU machine. I don't want to install any GUI on this machine, so I manually installed the NVIDIA driver (375.66) and CUDA toolkit using executable binary files downloaded from NVIDIA website rather than through APT.

However, it appears that the CUDA toolkit attempts to start X every time it is initialized. This causes `nvidia-smi` or other CUDA application to have 5-10 second delay.

I looked at `nvidia-xconfig` manual but couldn't find how to completely disable X. How can I make the NVIDIA toolkit to NOT attempt to start X?

Comment: Why would you install graphic drivers on a server?

Comment: Ever heard of CUDA?

Comment: Sure, but never one that runs on a server. Are you certain that X is not a requirement?

Comment: There are huge demands on that kind of servers for deep learning. Some may find X forwarding useful but that's not a requirement for me.

Comment: @Jos: It's pretty common to have (multiple) GPUs for computation on entirely headless systems. There are entire business models based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what eventually became different, but I installed NVIDIA driver 381.22 and the problem went away.

Comment: To mark this question as solved please press the tick underneath the number and arrows on this answer which will turn it into a beautiful green and mark this question as solved! :)